# Where is Heaphy Project for ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Heaphy Project is made by Willow Garage robotics lab.

It seems great for cloud robot.

The [website](https://heaphyrobotics.com/) is disappeared.

Is it opensource?

Where it go?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40583/where-is-heaphy-project-for-ros?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the answer from another [robotics site](http://forums.trossenrobotics.com/).

It says:

```
  I started the Heaphy project at Willow Garage with the goal of spinning it out as a commercial enterprise. At no stage was it open source. I left Willow at the end of March, however. As far as I know, nothing has been done with it since then.
  
  You might be able to email info@willowgarage.com to get more information on its current status.
  
  Cheers,
  Tim
```

---

Originally posted by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1